# Xcode 5.0.2 istant crash on Mavericks 10.9.1

Tags: xcode, macos, crash, osx-mavericks

I have a problem with Xcode 5.0.2 on Mavericks 10.9.1

The crash report is this:

http://pastebin.com/K6T4rc45

I have tried the following steps:

1. Rename/Delete */Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/IDEiPhoneSupport.ideplugin*
   and I'm able to open Xcode BUT not a project. For this problem [this
   link](http://pastebin.com/vGUEGsr6) is the crash report.
2. Re-download (after deleting the app from Applications and Trash).
3. Deleted the contents of *~/Library/Autosave Information/*
4. Deleted the contents of *~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*

How I can resolve this problem?

Edit 1: Deleted all relative files (with AppCleaner), rebooted, downloader Xcode from AppStore. All same. The command line works fine but not the IDE.

Comment: Have you tried just reinstalling Xcode completely?

Comment: Not completely. I deleted the Xcode app ad re-downloaded it. 
The command line tools works fine.

Comment: when this happens, is anything suspicion logged to Console?

Comment: I don't know what's do you mean with "suspicious" but the error came from a plugin. You can read the error in the first link.

Comment: yeah, that's the crash report, but is there anything in the system log from before the crash?

Comment: Do you see any I/O errors in your computer's system log? It could be that a particular sector on your hard drive is bad. I've seen weird problems like this occur under those circumstances.

Comment: Ok, in the syslog I have some Trap/Abort errors and `kernel: disk0s2: I/O error`
So this is my problem? Are the disk broken? :/

Comment: Try to scan for disk errors in the disk utility then

Comment: Checked the disk from USB Installation and repaired it. The error still occurs.

Comment: I have installed Xcode in another disk and the problem is same.